# Why should I log in if I can't vote or comment?

Tags: discussion

This has been a question nagging at me for the many years I have used Stack Overflow!

I can not comment, I don't have enough 'reputation points', I can not vote because I don't have enough 'reputation points'. I know I get points from asking questions, but after 30+ years of writing code, the questions I do have, have already been asked and answered. I can answer questions, but I have yet to find a question that does not have a good answer or answers.

I could do an end run, and ask questions I know the answer to just to get points, but that is not who I am. I feel a lot of questions on here are just for getting points (my opinion).

Any suggestions would be appreciated :)

P.S. Who created these rules.. I tried using 'reputation' as a keyword, but I don't have enough POINTS! Really??

Comment: Maybe the 'creators' could have given me the option of where to ask this. Good comment though, I will know in the future. Thank You for the vote. Like beating your son the first time he gets burned from a campfire!

Comment: My apologies :( And more excellent points. :)

Comment: Personally I have learnt a lot answering questions on this site over the last 4 years. The reputation system has its flaws but it has helped SO become arguably the best Q & A resource site on the internet.

Comment: [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: Possibly there is no particular benefit to you of being logged in. Do you have any favourited questions or favourite tags set up? Do you want any notifications on the few posts you have written?

Comment: @bjorn The question here is "what's the benefit of being logged in as a registered user if I don't have sufficient rep for basic participation ". Not "How do I get this rep".

Comment: Suggesting edits once logged in can get you reputation points. It's the easiest way to contribute.

Comment: Nope, if you don't participate (ask questions, write answers, *suggest edits*, did you try the latter yet?) then there is no point in you logging in. But did you know you can earn up to 1000 points by suggesting edits to posts? At +2 rep per accepted edit, to be able to vote up, you'd need to have 8 such edits accepted. To comment, 25. To vote down, 63. To continue to vote down on answers, a bit more (one suggested edit per two downvotes on answers).

Comment: As an aside, look at this question (apologies for the plug on my answer). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44206521/how-can-i-get-the-penultimate-element-in-a-list A brand new user, nicely written question, and already good reputation earned. That's one way to do it.

Comment: That user is able to make comments already, and they have been live for less than 1/2 hour.

Comment: *I have yet to find a question that does not have a good answer or answers* [Open questions with a non-negative score with zero answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0+closed%3Ano+score%3A0..). I don't know how many of those would be in your area of expertise but that's where I'd start if I wanted to answer something with no existing answers.

Comment: Regarding edits: If you do start making edits then, please, please, please fix all problems with the question. Don't just make a tag change on a question filled with grammar errors. Fix grammar & formatting, remove noise, don't bother editing something you know will get deleted (you'd lose the rep for that anyway), and don't bother adding in screenshots of text.